# Convolution of a signal with the butterworth filter.

Tags: proof-verification, convolution, filters

Let $f(t)$ be a signal that is $0$ when $t<0$ or $t>1$. Show that, for the Butterworth filter, one has
 $$Ae^{-\alpha t}\int_{0}^{\min\{t,1\}}e^{\alpha\tau}f(\tau)d\tau$$

My attempt:

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        L(f) =& \int_{-\infty}^\infty Ae^{-\alpha\tau}f(t-\tau)d\tau \\
         =& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}Ae^{-\alpha(t-\tau)}f(\tau)d\tau \\
        =& \int_{-\infty}^\infty Ae^{\alpha(\tau-t)}f(\tau)d\tau \\
        =& \int_{-\infty}^\infty Ae^{-\alpha t}e^{\alpha\tau}f(\tau)d\tau \\
        =& Ae^{-\alpha t}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\alpha\tau}f(\tau)d\tau
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
$f(\tau)\neq0$ if $\tau\in[0,1]$, 
and $Ae^{-\alpha(t-\tau)}\neq0$ if $t-\tau>0$.
Also, $f(t-\tau)\neq0$ if $0<t-\tau<1\Rightarrow t-1\leq0<\tau<t$.
But since $\tau<1$ and $\tau<1$, $\tau<\min\{t,1\}$.
$$\therefore L(f)=Ae^{-\alpha t}\int_0^{\min\{1,t\}}e^{\alpha\tau}f(\tau)d\tau,$$
$t>0$.

Is this correct? I find determining the bounds for convolutions of piecewise functions very confusing.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to show here, presumably that $$L(f) = a\star f $$ (where $a(t)=Ae^{\alpha t}$ is the impulse response of the filter?) is equal to $$Ae^{-\alpha t}\int_{0}^{\min\{t,1\}}e^{\alpha\tau}f(\tau)\ \mathsf d\tau\quad ? $$

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I eventually got:

$f(t)=0,t\notin[0,1]$, and $h(t)=Ae^{-\alpha t},t\geq0$.

\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        L(f) =& \int_{-\infty}^\infty Ae^{-\alpha\tau}f(t-\tau)d\tau \\
         =& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}Ae^{-\alpha(t-\tau)}f(\tau)d\tau \\
        =& \int_{-\infty}^\infty Ae^{\alpha(\tau-t)}f(\tau)d\tau \\
        =& \int_{-\infty}^\infty Ae^{-\alpha t}e^{\alpha\tau}f(\tau)d\tau \\
        =& Ae^{-\alpha t}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\alpha\tau}f(\tau)d\tau \\
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
$f(\tau)\neq0$ if $\tau\in[0,1]$, 
and $Ae^{-\alpha(t-\tau)}\neq0$ if $t-\tau>0$.
Also, $f(t-\tau)\neq0$ if $0<t-\tau<1\Rightarrow t-1\leq0<\tau<t$.
But since $\tau<1$ and $\tau<1$, $\tau<\min\{t,1\}$.
$$\therefore L(f)=Ae^{-\alpha t}\int_0^{\min\{1,t\}}e^{\alpha\tau}f(\tau)d\tau,$$
$t>0$.